# VbScript to launch URL in default browser from batch file argument

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a batch script `MyBatch.bat`, it successfully calls `MyVbScript.vbs` by the statement:

```
cscript //nologo %~dp0\MyVbScript.vbs %NewPort%
```

Where `NewPort` is a environment variable value.

`MyVbScript.vbs` is getting called successfully *(tested)* and value of `NewPort` is passed to VBS successfully *(tested)* from batch script.

But I am NOT able to generate the URL for launching in default browser. I want to generate the URL like `http://localhost:7006/MyWebApplication` where `7006` is value of `NewPort` variable.

MyVbScript.vbs contains:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsh
Dim port
Dim myNum

Set wsh=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
port = WScript.Arguments(0)

'MsgBox port//For testing
wsh.Run " "http://localhost:"&port&"/MyWebApplication" "

'End of VB script
```

How to generate the URL and launch it in default browser. I don't want to specify Chrome or Mozilla and IE because user may not have a particular browser.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
wsh.Run "http://localhost:"&port&"/MyWebApplication"
```

Any seasoned programmer can suggest other code too if I have written more LOC unnecessarily.